# Is this use of varargs safe?

Tags: java

I have a sort of util method to transform a varargs of a type into an array of that type - it looks like this:

```
public K[] array(K... ks) {
    return ks;
}
```

The use case is so that instead of defining an array when calling a method which requires an array, you can simply do array(val1, val2, val3).

However, IntelliJ gives me heap pollution warnings. I understand what this means to an extent, but I don't have much experience with the specifics - so, I would like to know whether I can add @SafeVarargs and whether this method is actually safe.

IntelliJ says:

> Problem synopsis      Possible heap pollution from parameterized
>   vararg type at line 249
>
> Problem resolution    Make final and annotate as @SafeVarargs

K is declared as the type parameter of a class, along with V.

Comment: IMO you don't need such method, just use `Whatever[] whateverArray = { val1, val2, val3, ...};`

Comment: Can you give *exact* details of the heap pollution warning? And where is the type parameter `K` declared?

Comment: @Luiggi, yeah, but it's a utility. `K[] keys = { key1, key2, key3 }; object.method(keys);` vs `object.method(array(key1, key2, key3));` - the second is much easier to write, especially when you're doing it a lot.

Comment: No, it isn't. And if you need to create such array in the fly, do it like this: `foo.method(new Whatever[] { val1, val2, val3, ... });`. There's no need for your *utility* method.

Comment: @Luiggi there is no need for any utility method, that's the point. It's a utility method which makes it easier. It's so much cleaner to not have loads of {} everywhere, especially considering my use case actually has three arrays in the same method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: It is *clearly* less verbose/visually-distracting to write `foo(array(a, b, c))` than it is to write `foo(new Whatever[]{a, b, c})`.

Comment: @Jon more details added to the question :)

Comment: Then don't use raw Arrays, that is a code smell in and of it self; unless you are working with a legacy API that requires it. If you solely want the syntactic sugar, then use the appropriate Google Guava builder to return a type safe list instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, it's not safe - if called from another method which is using generics. Here's a complete example which *looks* okay, but throws an exception:

```
class Utility<K> {   
    public K[] array(K... ks) {
        return ks;
    }

    public K[] otherMethod(K k1, K k2) {
        return array(k1, k2);
    }
}    

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Utility<String> util = new Utility<String>();
        // Bang!
        String[] array = util.otherMethod("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

When the compiler creates the bytecode for `otherMethod`, it *can't* create an array of the right kind to pass into `array`, because it doesn't know the type of `K`. Due to type erasure, it just creates an `Object[]` with the values. So in `main`, there's a hidden cast from the result of `otherMethod` to `String[]`... and that fails at execution time.

If you call `array` directly from code which *really* knows the types of the arguments, then it's fine, because the implicitly-created array will be of the right type.

Comment: thank you. as long as this is the only (within reason) situation which could cause a problem it should be fine for what I'm doing.

Comment: Use real caution here, @DziNeIT. If it's just a folly and you're the only person using this code, then go ahead. I know what my opinion would be if I came across something like this, however. It's a good question with an equally good answer, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just tell your method how to convert to the appropriate array. One way I found was to pass the array into the method with the variables, and then copy to it.

```
public K[] otherMethod(K[] parent, K k1, K k2) {
    List<K> list = new ArrayList<K>();
    Collections.addAll(list, array(k1, k2));
    list.toArray(parent);
    return parent;
}
```

Now the output depends on the Collections.toArray() method, which returns null if there isn't enough space in the array, or if there is extra space the unused values will be null.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Utility<String> util = new Utility<String>();
        String[] array = util.array("one", "two", "three");
        array = util.otherMethod(array, "x", "y");
        printArr(array); // prints: x    y    null

        Utility<Integer> util2 = new Utility<Integer>();
        Integer[] intarray = util2.otherMethod(new Integer[1], 1, 2);
        printArr(intarray); // prints: null
        Integer[] intarray = util2.otherMethod(new Integer[2], 1, 2);
        printArr(intarray); // prints: 1    2
    }

    static void printArr(Object[] objArr) {
        for (Object o:objArr) System.out.print(o+"\t");
    }
}
```